# Fast reading from HDD for Linux - strange phenomenon

Tags: c++, c, linux, solid-state-drive

[Sorry for the confusion: The original post had "SSD" instead of "HDD" in the title, but I figured out that I performed the tests on an HDD by accident, as I was accessing the wrong mounting point. On an SSD this phenomenon did not occur. Still interesting that it happens for an HDD though.]

I am using the following code for reading in a loop from a given number of files of constant size. All files to be read exist and reading is successful.

It is clear that varying the file size has an effect on `fMBPerSecond`, because when reading files smaller than the page size, still the whole page is read. However, `nNumberOfFiles` has an effect on `fMBPerSecond` as well, which is what I do not understand. Apparently, it is not `nNumberOfFiles` itself that has an effect, but it is the product `nNumberOfFiles * nFileSize`.

But why should it have an effect? The files are opened/read/closed sequentially in a loop.

I tested with `nFileSize = 65536`. When choosing `nNumberOfFiles = 10000` (or smaller) I get something around `fMBPerSecond = 500 MB/s`.  With `nNumberOfFiles = 20000` I get something around `fMBPerSecond = 100 MB/s`, which is a dramatic loss in performance.

Oh, and I should mention that I clear the disk cache before reading by executing:

```
sudo sync
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Any ideas what is happening here behind the scenes would be welcome.

*Pedram*

```
void Read(int nFileSize, int nNumberOfFiles)
{
    char szFilePath[4096];

    unsigned char *pBuffer = new unsigned char[nFileSize];

    Helpers::get_timer_value(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < nNumberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        sprintf(szFilePath, "files/test_file_%.4i", i);

        int f = open(szFilePath, O_RDONLY);

        if (f)
        {
            if (read(f, pBuffer, (ssize_t) nFileSize) != (ssize_t) nFileSize)
                printf("error: could not read file '%s'\n", szFilePath);

            close(f);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error: could not open file for reading '%s'\n", szFilePath);
        }
    }

    const unsigned int t = Helpers::get_timer_value();

    const float fMiliseconds = float(t) / 1000.0f;
    const float fMilisecondsPerFile = fMiliseconds / float(nNumberOfFiles);
    const float fBytesPerSecond = 1000.0f / fMilisecondsPerFile * float(nFileSize);
    const float fMBPerSecond = fBytesPerSecond / 1024.0f / 1024.0f;

    printf("t = %.8f ms / %.8i bytes - %.8f MB/s\n", fMilisecondsPerFile,
        nFileSize, fMBPerSecond);

    delete [] pBuffer;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason to mark it c++, or even any language?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware performance and seems to be unrelated to programming.

Comment: Try shuffling the indices of the files you access.  Perhaps the first 10000 or whatever are laid out more optimally on the disk.

Comment: I thought it is relevant that it is somewhat low-level access and not an interpreted language such as Java, plus the example code is C/C++. If the tags C and C++ are misleading or not useful, I can remove them though.

Comment: There's some latency in opening/closing files, no?

Comment: @alk Only in C's dreams. ;-)

Comment: I will try to shuffle the indices, but I don't think it will have an effect, because when I half the number of files, but double the file size, the phenomenon is the same, which is why I said I it seems like the product, i.e. the total number of bytes, is relevant.

Comment: I know that syntactically it is not C. But the file access is C, which is more relevant than the syntax in this context, I guess.

Comment: Perhaps you're exceeding an SSD-internal cache space then.

Comment: It is an addition, but with system specific coefficients: `K1 * number_of_write + K2 * number_of_files`. `K1` and `K2` describe the impact in terms of delay imposed per operation.

Comment: It would be nice if someone has an idea, if this is more related to the SSD, or to the controller, or to the operating system.

Comment: Another possibility is that cache is still a concern--the kernel may start evicting cached pages beyond a certain number of bytes accessed, reducing performance.

Comment: @alk: Good point. I will look into that.

Comment: @MischNix: Good point, too. Thank you everybody for your comments.

Comment: @alk: When I close the file, can I assume that operations on that file are completed fully, or can there be some pending internal stuff that is executed by the OS asynchronously?

Comment: Is the timing the same if you don't do the `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` beforehand?

Comment: @jwpat7: When I remove that, then it runs at 3000 MB/s, no matter if 10000 oder 20000 files.

Comment: POSIX defines I/O using `open()/read()/write()/close()` to be unbuffered, so from the processes' perspective data had been written when `close()` returns. What the lower levels **really** do is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

There are several SSD models, especially the more expensive datacenter models, that combine an internal DRAM cache with the (slower) persistent NAND cells. As long as the data you read fits in the DRAM cache, you'll get faster response.